# Calculate velocity of object on which multiple forces are acting

Tags: vectors, physics

**Question:**
How do I calculate the velocity of an object on which multiple forces are acting, at any given moment (in a 2D space)? The forces could have been applied at different moments.

**The Problem:**
I have an object on which multiple forces are acting at the same time. I have thought of these forces as vectors with a magnitude (in N) and an angle (in Deg).

I have already figured out how to get the resultant vector with the right magnitude and angle. With this, I could calculate the object's acceleration, using Newton's 2nd law: $F = ma$

To get the velocity at any given time, I need to get the time since the force was applied and use it in the formula: $v = at$. But what happens when two forces get applied at different times? What should I use for $t$? I already know the result acceleration and angle, but just don't know what to use for $t$.

**Example:** An object in 2D space, which has a mass of $1 kg$, is moving to the right with an acceleration of $5m/s^2$, after 3 seconds, it is moving to the right with a velocity of $15 m/s$. Then, it gets pushed with a force of $10 N$ from the bottom, which gives it an acceleration of $10m/s^2$ towards the top. What would be the velocity of the object 10 seconds later?

Comment: I don't see where two forces are being applied at different times? In your example you can now work out a resultant acceleration (it is a vector) and go from there.

Comment: Deal the question by solving separately for x and y axes.

Comment: In a general case, where the force is not constant, you would have to integrate the acceleration vector over time to get the velocity vector. In the example, the forces are constant, so you just have to add up the vectors: v = 15.[1,0] + 100.[0,1] = [15,100]. The magnitude is sqrt(15^2 + 100^2) the angle is atan(100/15).

Comment: @Paul If I first push the object to the right and 3 seconds later I push it to the top, two forces would be applied at different times, right? To get the velocity, I need the time since the force was applied, but what time do I use? If I use the time since the new force was applied, I would get a velocity of 0 at that moment, which is obviously not correct, as the object is still moving to the right.

Comment: To clarify, I already have calculated the result acceleration and angle, but don't know what to use for t

Comment: @KnoquerBonk Why not handle it piecewise? Before each new constant force is applied, calculate the final velocity vector. This becomes the initial velocity when a new constant net force is applied.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio That seems like a good idea, but I don't know how I would then integrate that initial velocity in the new net force.

Comment: @KnoquerBonk lmk if my answer makes sense

Comment: @Golden_Ratio It definitely does! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the outline of what you can do: a constant net force of $F_t$ acts on an object of mass $m$ between time $t$ and $t'$. If the object's velocity is $v_t$ at time $t$, then its velocity at time $t'$ is

$$v_{t'}=v_t+(F_t/m)(t'-t).$$

This becomes the initial velocity at time $t'$ at which a new constant net force $F_{t'}$ is applied and you just rinse and repeat.